# sails command not working in windows8 instead it opens notepad with some script

Tags: sails.js

Here are my prompt command logs from when it was installed on my system:

```
C:\Users\shiva.namburu>npm install sails -g
    \

sails@0.11.2 preinstall C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\sails
node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js
Sails.js Installation: Checking npm-version successful
npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme: https://git

hub.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib

bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\eng
ine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
node-gyp rebuild
-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node
modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\n
odejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gy
p.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sail
s-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\no
de_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The import
ed project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the pat
h in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modu
les\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node
modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_mo
dules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules
\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
node-gyp rebuild
C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails
-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node
modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Fil
es\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\nod
e-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sail
s-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\no
de_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The im
ported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the
path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modu
les\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node
modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_mo
dules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1

utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_
modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
node-gyp rebuild
C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails
-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
odules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\no
de-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sail
s-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node
modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj(20,3): error M
SB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Co
nfirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file e
xists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modu
les\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node
modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-
client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1

bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modu
les\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
node-gyp rebuild
C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails
-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
odules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\P
rogram Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-g
yp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sail
s-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node
modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB40
19: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confir
m that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exist
s on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modu
les\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\shiva.namburu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node
modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-
client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1
```

Even if I clear the cache with the `npm clear cache` command, the problem remains the same.

How I can install sails globally?

Answer (score 1):

You have issue with compiling native modules.

Install build tools and run install again.

You can read more about this here - https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation

Comment: I set the PYTHON path and installed MSVS 2013 as per the doc says still the problem remians